# Creating List From Dictionary that Specifies Position by Index and Skips Some Index Positions

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I am working with the following dictionary:

```
d = {'inds':[0, 3, 7, 3, 3, 5, 1], 'vals':[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]}
```

I am wanting to create a new_list that takes the values in list `d['vals']` and places them in new_list by corresponding index in list `d['inds']`.  The ultimate result should be:

```
[1.0, 7.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 3.0]
```

This takes the following:

```
d['inds'] == [0,   3,   7,   3,   3,   5,   1]

d['vals'] == [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
```

For any index position not included in `d['inds']` the corresponding value is 0.0.

For index positions that are repeated, the `True` value for that position is the sum of the individual values.  For example, above 3 is repeated 3 times; so, `new_list[3]` should `== 11`, which is the sum of 2.0 + 4.0 + 5.0.

Comment: You should show what you have tried, what specifically is not working in your code, not, how do I do this

Answer (score 2):

First, allocate a list of the appropriate length and full of zeroes:

```
result = [0] * (max(d['inds']) + 1)
```

Then loop over the indices and values and add them to the values in the list:

```
for ind, value in zip(d['inds'], d['vals']):
    result[ind] += value
```

Output:

```
>>> result
[1.0, 7.0, 0, 11.0, 0, 6.0, 0, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

After collaborating with a co-worker, who helped walked me through this, the following was arrived at for a more dynamic function (to allow for different lengths of the resulting list):

```
import numpy as np
d ={
    'inds': [0,3,7,3,3,5,1],
    'vals': list(range(1,8))}  
    ## this assumes the values in the list associated with the 'vals' key
    ## remain in numerical order due to range function.  


def newlist(dictionary, length) ##length must be at least max(d['inds'])+1
    out = np.zeroes(length)
    for i in range (len(dictionary['inds'])):
        out[dictionary['inds'][i]] += d['vals'][i]

    return(out)
```